# I can't create a XAML/DirectX app in C# for Windows 8?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-8, sdk

I'm developing a game for Windows Phone 8, and since I know C# ALOT better then C++ I picked

"Windows Phone XAML and Direct3D App" since XNA is dead. But in addition to my windows phone app I would like to make a windows 8 app for win8 and win8 rt.

I've just installed VS Express for Windows 8, but I cant find this project template for Windows 8 in the C# section. The ones i have are:

- Blank App (XAML)
- Grid App (XAML)
- Split App (XAML)
- Class ligrary
- Windows Runtime Component
- Unit Test Library?

Comment: All of the templates are Windows Store application templates.  You also need a developer key otherwise you won't be able to publish your application.

Comment: @Ramhound thats all well and good, but I should be able to browse all the templates?

Comment: Those are all the templates?  Any other templates are not default templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 3 XAML templates that you listed are the ones that exist for doing XAML with C#.  To do DirectX with C#, there are no templates (there are only DirectX templates for C++).  The way to get around this is to use SharpDX, which will allow you to use C# and DirectX together.  Here are some links to get you started:

- http://code.google.com/p/sharpdx/
- http://www.sharpdx.com/documentation/

Comment: Yes, but with Microsoft killing XNA, what future does SharpDX have? Could i do C#+SharpDX for both windows 8 and windows phone 8? I'm a big fan of not wirting the same code more then once. It should be this way... it is "windows".

Comment: @Jason94 - You won't be able to write a universal application that supports `Windows Store` and `Windows Phone 8` so you will have to accept that. Besides `SharpDX` isn't XNA its `DirectX`.

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, but since SharpDX aint made by Microsoft they could easily kill it im afraid.

Comment: @Jason94 - Microsoft can't kill SharpDX without killing `DirectX` and even if `SharpDX` stops being updated you can update it yourself.  The alternative is to use C++ and `DirectX` directly.

Comment: But why can you with the WP8 SDK create a c# project of the type XAML+Direct3D and not in Windows 8?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Monogame](http://www.monogame.net/) to write C#/XNA games for Windows Runtime/ Windows Phone 8.  Monogame is an open source implementation of XNA, and uses SharpDX under the hood to target Windows.

Note that Monogame isn't yet feature complete and is missing things like the content pipeline. There are however, workarounds for this.